# Get Row Data from Data table having a column as input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with a column with an input field.
To get the data from table I'm using:

```
table.rows().data().toArray();
```

I'm getting the result array, but for the column with input field I'm getting the whole html of input field and not just the value.
eg. `'<input type="text" value="someValue"></input>'`

How can I manipulate the code to get the value of input in result array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table
  .rows()
  .data()
  .toArray()
  .map((el) => {
   if(el.includes('<input')){
    return el.split('value="')[1].split('"')[0]
   }
  })
```